# QoQ Calculation Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I'm calculating QoQ Imp and QoQ %Eng in the below data table which is grouped by with the help of power query by adding "Index starting from 0" and "Index.1 starting from 1".

[image]

I have a "filter" column in the Filters pane this visual. Please help me in calculating QoQ Imp and QoQ %Eng in the above Table A. The expected result/output should look like this below table:-
[image]

Comment: What is the logic of those calculations?

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query (M Code), assuming your data is representative, you can compute the QoQ values before filtering/grouping etc.

- Add your Index column as you show
- Then add a Modulo column (value = 4, since you have four quarters)
- Then add custom columns for your two calculations:
  [image]

[image]

- Then filter as needed

Here is the M Code assuming the data source is an Excel Table.  Modify the Source line as needed

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table7"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Qtr", type text}, {"Filter", type text}, {"Imp", Int64.Type}, {"Eng", Int64.Type}}),

//Compute % Eng column
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "% Eng", each [Eng]/[Imp], Percentage.Type),

//Add Index and Modulo columns
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index], 4), type number),
 
 //Compute QOQs -- (current row - previous row)/previous row (unless first row in the group in which case => null
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Modulo", "QoQ Imp", each if [Modulo]=0 then null
        else ([Imp] - #"Inserted Modulo"[Imp]{[Index]-1}) / #"Inserted Modulo"[Imp]{[Index]-1}),
 
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "QoQ %Eng", each if [Modulo]=0 then null
        else ([#"% Eng"] - #"Inserted Modulo"[#"% Eng"]{[Index]-1}) / #"Inserted Modulo"[#"% Eng"]{[Index]-1}),

//remove now superfluous Index and Modulo columns and re-order the others
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"Index", "Modulo"}),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Removed Columns",{"Qtr", "Filter", "Imp", "QoQ Imp", "Eng", "% Eng", "QoQ %Eng"})
in
    #"Reordered Columns"
```

[image]